# Ideal chunk in scala fs2 stream performance gain in production

Tags: scala, java-stream, scalaz, scalaz-stream, fs2

was wondering if the increase in chunk size in [scala fs2 stream](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) will give the performance gain?

```
    import cats.effect.{IO, Sync}
import fs2.{io, text}
import java.nio.file.Paths

def fahrenheitToCelsius(f: Double): Double =
  (f - 32.0) * (5.0/9.0)

def converter[F[_]](implicit F: Sync[F]): F[Unit] =
  io.file.readAll[F](Paths.get("testdata/fahrenheit.txt"), 4096)
    .through(text.utf8Decode)
    .through(text.lines)
    .filter(s => !s.trim.isEmpty && !s.startsWith("//"))
    .map(line => fahrenheitToCelsius(line.toDouble).toString)
    .intersperse("\n")
    .through(text.utf8Encode)
    .through(io.file.writeAll(Paths.get("testdata/celsius.txt")))
    .compile.drain

// at the end of the universe...
val u: Unit = converter[IO].unsafeRunSync()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chunk size is just a size of the buffer used when you read the file content from the file system. So your question is equivalent to "will increasing buffer size when reading the file give performance gain?".

This question is OS/hardware specific. Short answer for most cases - 4K is enough.

Comment: yes, my question is if we increase the buffer size then will it give performance gain.

Comment: Then most probably you should stay on 4-8K. Tuning in without specific expertise would be a shot in the dark.